# Encryption with Wrapped key not working in Swift

Tags: swift, security, encryption, cryptography

1. First I generated 512 bits of key, called "Wrapped Key" and save into keychain
2. Generated another key 512 bits of key, called "private Key"
3. Converted this "private Key" into data, data count is 319 bytes
4. Retrieve "Wrapped Key" from keychain
5. Get Public Key from  "Wrapped Key"
6. Try to encrypt "private Key" of data with "Wrapped Key"(public key)
7. It gives error for any algorithm I tried so far.

my code is as follow:

```
    guard let privateKeyData = KeyManager.keyToData(key: privateKey)
         else {
                debugPrint("private Key Data not found")
                return
            }
            
            var error : Unmanaged<CFError>?
            let pubKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(wrappedKey)
            
            ///2. Encrypt Private key by Wrapped Key
            guard let encryptedPrivateKey = SecKeyCreateEncryptedData(pubKey!, .eciesEncryptionStandardX963SHA1AESGCM, data as CFData, &error) as Data? else {
                debugPrint("encryption error private key")
                debugPrint(error!.takeUnretainedValue())
                return
            }
```

**Error:**

> UserInfo={numberOfErrorsDeep=0, NSDescription=algid:encrypt:ECIES:ECDH:KDFX963:SHA1:AESGCM: algorithm not supported by the key <SecKeyRef algorithm id: 1, key type: RSAPublicKey, version: 4, 512 bits (block size: 64),

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error that you get?

Comment: @Timmy, added error in the question

Comment: Have you tried using a 256 key? As the error suggests that the algorithm you're using does not support your key.

Comment: Actually I want to use specific 512 bit key only, with 256 it is working @Timmy

Comment: The **wrapping key** is the one used for protecting the other key, which is called the **wrapped key**. I think in this post you are confusing the two. Also I'm wondering how you can make this work with a 256 bit RSA key. You should only be able to make it work with a 256 bit EC *wrapping* key pair and any type and size of private key to be wrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

512 bit RSA is not secure and should not be used. RSA is relatively secure when used with key sizes starting at 2048 bits giving ~112 bits of security, and 3072 bits giving ~128 bits of security.

Note that the description of the algorithm in the error indicates that the wrapping is performed using `ECIES:ECDH:KDFX963:SHA1:AESGCM`. Currently you are providing an RSA key instead of the required elliptic curve key.

The algorithm means:

- ECIES: hybrid encryption using key agreement and a symmetric algorithm, in this case ECDH and an AES mode
- ECDH: that's generic key agreement, **which requires a ECDH public key to be supplied**, this parameterizes ECIES with a specific key agreement
- KDFX963: a KDF construction to derive the (AES) key from the ECDH protocol, this parameterizes the ECDH key agreement scheme
- SHA1: the parameterization of the KDF with the necessary hash function
- AESGCM: the encryption algorithm that performs the actual wrapping, parameterizing ECIES with the necessary symmetric cipher

That's a lot of information, but in the end it comes down that only ECDH needs another input parameter: the EC public key. The scheme uses AES in GCM mode to encrypt, so in principle the size of the key-to-be-wrapped is of no consequence.

What is of consequence is that the *wrapping key* needs to be of the correct type, as ECDH will never work with an RSA key. Try to use a EC key pair, say with curve P-256 instead. If you want ~512 bit EC keys giving 256 bit security you could use P-521 (not a typo).

Comment: Do you know how can we generate private keys & save into keychain at build time using shell script in iOS?